# Unable to load DLL 'sni.dll' - Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core

When using Entity Framework Core in an ASP.Net Core application on Visual Studio 2017 I intermittently get the error "Unable to load 'sni.dll'.

Strangely though I have found a temporary fix: restarting my PC.

I don't know why the error keeps happening, I don't know what the variable could be. Could anyone shed light on the possible cause? I would offer a full stack trace but it hasn't happened since deciding to post on here, when it next happens I'll be sure to update this. I know for certain though (as the debug catches the exception) that it happens when EF has cause to get data from the db and transform to entities.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

--EDIT
This is still happening. Managed to remember to capture the stack trace:

> System.DllNotFoundException occurred
>     HResult=0x80131524
>     Message=Unable to load DLL 'sni.dll': The specified network name is no longer available. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070040)
>     Source=
>     StackTrace:
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper.UnmanagedIsTokenRestricted(IntPtr token, Boolean& isRestricted)
>      at System.Data.Win32NativeMethods.IsTokenRestrictedWrapper(IntPtr token)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolIdentity.GetCurrent()
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolGroup.GetConnectionPool(DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPool(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionPoolGroup connectionPoolGroup)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded, TState state)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_Include>d__30`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass20_0`1.<CompileQueryCore>b__0(QueryContext qc)
>      at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adding nuget package System.Data.SqlClient v4.4.0 solved the same problem for me. The problem is not specific to Entity Framework. It is caused by older version of SqlClient dependency on APIs not available in dotnet Core 2.

Comment: Perfect. Yeah that seems to have worked. Because of its intermittent nature I can't say for certain, only time will tell I guess. But I'll mark this answer as correct. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In my case it was a matter of updating the NuGet package for System.Data.SqlClient.  I wouldn't have guessed it based on the error.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

In some instances this issue can be caused by IIS not having sufficient permissions to access areas of your %USERPROFILE%.nuget

**This can be solved in one of two simple ways:**

Grant permission to the IIS appPool (like DefaultAppPool or FooAppPool) to access not only the .Nuget folder (this is usually done automatically).

Set the AppPool being used to run as 'LocalSystem' under Identity, this way the appPool will be treated as having higher permissions and should have access.

Here's a series of references for where other users have had this error, 'solved' several years ago:

```
https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements-discussions/issues/9
https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5262
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/5252
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30518
```

All of these reference the version of SQLClient (while this is relevant, it's a legacy issue), but one smart guy [@azisoft](https://github.com/azisoft) ([this link](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5262)) realised this and has helped many thanks to it.

Answer (score 9):

For Entity Framework Core 3.x, install the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` Nuget package instead of `System.Data.SqlClient`.

Comment: I'm getting the same error and I have the *Microsoft.Data.SqlClient* package installed.

Comment: @JonathanWood Have you tried installing it (and presumably the EF Core packages?) into every project in your solution? Then if it works, you can narrow down which projects actually need it?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same Problem with a .NET 4.8 WebApplication with MVC5 and WebApi that is using EF Core 3.15.

Out code is seperated in several Projects. I only addeded the EF Core References to the Projects that needs to access DB. This leads to the same Problem as you guys have here.

After i added the EF Core References also to the startup Project it works as intended.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: In this same scenario, I found that i only needed to install Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to my startup project

Answer (score 2):

This is occurred due to System.Data.SqlClient.TO resolve that,

1)Right click on your project and click on manage nuget package.

2)install Microsoft.Data.SqlClient instaed of System.Data.SqlClient

3)rebuild project and publish

(I am using .net core 2.0 web api)

Comment: Why repeat an existing answer?

Answer (score 1):

For me, a little modified nate's way, worked for me:

```xml
<Import
   Project="$(NuGetPackageRoot)Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.1.1.0\build\net46\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.targets"
   Condition="Exists('$(NuGetPackageRoot)Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.1.1.0\build\net46\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.targets')" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using source control where EFCore was newly added when pulling changes, try restore nuget packages and then close and reopen Visual Studio.

Our current guessing that this line in the project file wasn't executing correctly when the package was restored

```
<Import Project="..\..\packages\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.1.1.0\build\net46\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.1.1.0\build\net46\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.targets')" />
```

This seems like a silly answer but it just worked for us.