# Azure Function 3.0.1 on netcore3.1 System.Data.SqlClient: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, azure-functions

I am using the latest version of azure functions 3.0.1 and .net core 3.1. ( The following question look familiar but it didn't help me so creating a new one [Azure functions runtime exception, the type initializer for system data sqlclient excetion, Unable to load DLL 'sni.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58833050/azure-functions-runtime-exception-the-type-initializer-for-system-data-sqlclien) )

I want to mention here that this same code works fine with azure function 2 and .net core 2.2

**Another important information is I am using NHibernate and this error comes when executing cfg.BuildSessionFactory(); command.**

The runtime error is:

**A host error has occurred during startup operation '3756a542-87f8-43dd-a977-fbf87c7597d1'.
[12/11/2019 5:17:42 AM] System.Data.SqlClient: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception. System.Data.SqlClient: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle' threw an exception. System.Data.SqlClient: Unable to load DLL 'sni.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E).**

Here is the part of .csproj file.

```
 <PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
   <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="3.1.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.1" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

Also, the following package was added instead of system.data.sqlclient as a solution but both give same error.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="1.1.0" />
```

I have followed everything from this link https://dev.to/azure/develop-azure-functions-using-net-core-3-0-gcm to set up a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a nuget reference to  System.Data.SqlClient v4.4.0. This is described in  [Resolution to missing sni.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45992774/8597329)

Comment: Yes, sir, I tried that solution also but to no avail. I have added two more statements, I am using nhibernate 5.2.6 which causes the error and this code works fine with azure 2/core 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. after reading https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1370.

add to the local.settings.json this

"FUNCTIONS_V2_COMPATIBILITY_MODE":  "true"

Comment: Thank you Ram for taking time to reply. I had put this on hold with your reply I tried again. That solution did not work in my demo app. I am thinking that demo project itself has some environment issue as I was able to convert the actual project to .net core 3.1 and function 3. If I get time will look into that and post findings. For now this is not an issue anymore for me. Thanks. :)

Comment: Update: I compared the dependencies between the two project and updated according to working project. I was using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, I changed it to System.Data.SqlClient, and it worked. But I can vouch I had changed it to microsoft.data.sqlclient as system.data.sqlclient was not working. Anyways finally got it working:)

Comment: @Raj I'm using system.data.sql v- 4.6.0 nuget and it works for me. I glad that finally you are able to make this work with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I changed package from `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` to use `System.Data.SqlClient` and the error gone.

Note: I had changed it to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` as `System.Data.SqlClient` was giving same error. May be there was an update in the package or recent Visual Studio updates may have fixed it, I am not sure. But the error gone by making this change. Thanks all.